# Adding NSString to NSMutableArray substitutes the previous NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray

I'm basically trying to add a new string to my NSMutableArray using this code in `ViewWillAppear`

```
    NSUserDefaults *favBooksDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    self.favBook = [favBooksDefaults stringForKey:@"favBook"];
    self.favBookList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self.favBookList addObject:favBook];
```

Of course, while I do this, I want to preserve ALL the previous strings that were present in the Array. Because when I add a new string for the NSUserDefaults and then to the Array, it simply substitutes the old one.

Why is that and how can I save all the objects?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want self.favBookList to contain multiple strings? And self.favBook is a string that you want to add? If so, notice that you're initializing a new array, so self.favBookList will be empty after the third line, and will contain the new string after the fourth line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr Br.'s answer is correct:

In your header file declare favBookList as a property and include a book adding method:

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController {
NSMutableArray *favBookList;
}

-(void)addBook;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *favBookList;
```

In your viewDidLoad method, initialize favBookList.  Don't forget @synthesize!

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
self.favBookList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Now you are free to add a book from your user defaults at any time.

```
-(void)addBook{
self.favBook = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"favBook"];
[favBookList addObject:favBook]; 
}
```

Comment: The problem still remains. My NSMutableArray saves only _the last_ added object, _without_ remembering the previous ones. I always end up getting an array with just **ONE** object. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: If you're looking to store your entries through multiple app launches then you would need to write to core data or something like that, but I don't see how this would still cause an issue if the view controller remains on the stack.

Comment: I think I'm just going to write the data to the plist, and retrieve it from from it every time the view loads. Thanks a lot for your assistant!

Answer (score 1):

When you alloc and init a new NSMutableArray object you will have an empty array with no values in it. It doesn't substitute it as there is nothing to substitute in there. It just adds the NSSString as the first value. This of course happens EVERY time you alloc/init a new instance of NSMutableArray.

SOLUTION: Make the NSMutableArray a instance variable of your view controller. alloc/init it once (e.g. in the viewDidLoad). Every time `viewWillAppear` gets called you can add values without reinitializing a new NSMutableArray.

Comment: hm you create a instance variable of type of NSMutableArray and init it in your viewDidLoad. That's all. You can use the exact same code as you already posted just leave out the line where you alloc/init a new NSMutableArray

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldArray];
[newArray replaceObjectAtIndex:oldObjectIndex withObject:newObject] // if you want to replace oldObject with newObject;
[newArray addObject:newObject] // if you want to add object to the array;
```

If i get it right you want to replace the old object with new one?

Comment: You got it backwards, I just want to ADD a new elements, WHILE keeping the old one in there

Comment: read the comment - i provide you with two methods :) 1. to replace, 2. to add. You create array by using the old array and use the addobject method :)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSUserDefaults *favBooksDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.favBook = [favBooksDefaults stringForKey:@"favBook"];
if ([self.favBookList indexOfObject:self.favBook] != NSNotFound) {
    [self.favBookList addObject:favBook];
}
```

You should also init your favBookList in `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.favBookList = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: The thing with self.favBookList = [NSMutableArray array]; doesn't work, no matter where I put it